# Is there a Mushroom collector in Paldea?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

An [Item Maniac](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Item_maniac) is a person who will purchase certain items from the player at a higher price than what they would be sold for, like in 5th generation games. I own several valuable items and I want to sell them at the best price.

The description for the Big Mushroom suggests it:

> It's extremely popular with a certain class of collectors.

Is there a Mushroom collector in Paldea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Mushroom Collector is missing from Pokemon Scarlet/Violet.
You cannot sell the Mushrooms in the game to a Mushroom Collector, because the game does not have Item Maniacs like the previous titles that buy the items for high prices.

You can head over to a Pokemart and sell the mushrooms there, at a lower price.

Comment: Not sure if it's just a coincidence, but this answer is near word-for-word from [here](https://digistatement.com/pokemon-scarlet-violet-sv-is-there-a-mushroom-collector-to-sell-mushrooms/)

Comment: @Wondercricket kinda inspired from there, didn't want to add the source since it's not an official page